# Help soundproofing already built room

Tags: sound-proofing, noise, sounds

I need to make a music room in my house. I have to soundproof it so no noise can leave it (i dont care if noise enters). I'm also on a budget. The only non electric instruments I have are saxophones and a trumpet. So if you guys have any tips to prevent others from hearing those instruments. Please let me know. This is also my first home project. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of past soundproofing questions?

Comment: If the non-electronic are wind instruments, does that mean there *are* electric guitars, electronic keyboards, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

I've attempted to build a reasonably soundproof music room in my basement and can tell you it is a tall order.  I built a room when finishing my basement using double drywall with Green Glue, a floating double drywall ceiling with hat channel and isolation clips, sealed outlets, and re-routed HVAC and it I can still only play at a moderate volume without disturbing the peace upstairs.

The best thing you can do is build a room within your room that is structurally separated from the existing walls and ceiling.  Fill the space in between with Roxul Safe and Sound Insulation (Lowes). It's the best option but still has limitations and is not cheap.  There are many examples if you Google it.

If the room already exists and you're on a tight budget, you can just do your best to hang heavy material on the walls like quilts, etc. and isolate anything that generates sound from the surfaces of the room with rubber mats, mouse pads, etc. Also avoid cutting holes in the ceiling for recessed lighting etc. Use lamps or surface mount lights. Anything you can do to reduce vibration (sound) from getting to the existing structure of your house will help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And, seriously, consider suitable headphones as an alternative. Much less expensive than letting an electronic instrument scream and then try to mute it. Doesn't solve the problem for trumpet and sax unless you invest in synth controllers for those, but that may actually be cheaper than trying to isolate a mini-studio.

Comment: For guitar amplifiers, building an isolation cabinet is also a reasonable solution.  Mic it and run it into your recording interface and then use headphones as @keshlam suggested.

Comment: Or consider amp/cabinet emulation effects; there's some good software out there that can accurately simulate a wide range of classic and modern amps and speakers. It sounds like your next investment is going to be a DAW anyway....

Comment: Btw, there are some excellent home-studio websites out there; you should definitely do some searching.